# "Report Ad" with diagnostic information fails in Firefox

Tags: bug, advertising, firefox

In Firefox, when I checked "Share diagnostic information" on the advertising report form and submitted it, an error occurred and I was unable to report it. This seems to be because `navigator.userAgentData` does not exist in Firefox.

This issue was [reported](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3931/#comment4089_3931) on the Japanese version of StackOverflow.
However, it is a common problem for all languages and sites.

Below is the error message displayed in the developer tools console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: navigator.userAgentData is undefined
    getBrowserVersion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    gatherDiagnosticInfo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    submitForm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    initForm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    initForm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    loadModal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    onButtonClick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    callOnButtonClick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920:9308
    submitForm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    AsyncFunctionThrow self-hosted:856
    (Async: async)
    initForm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    initForm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    loadModal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    AsyncFunctionNext self-hosted:852
    (Async: async)
    onButtonClick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
    callOnButtonClick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968195/ansible-dynamic-variable-content:1920
```

Comment: Safari also does not support `navigator.userAgentData`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData